# Daterange Error in Python

Tags: python

Wrote a snippet in python that extracts data from database and displays them on the python shell,However there is some silly mistake I am making,since I only get a single date instead of dates in a range.
My code is as follows:

```
# open a database connection
connection = MySQLdb.connect ()

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = connection.cursor ()

# execute the SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute ()

data = cursor.fetchall()
ddt =  sorted(set(data))

def dte():
  for row in ddt:
   date = (' '.join(map(str,row)))
  return date

print dte()
```

This is the output that I get: 2017-11-09
But Instead I should get multiple dates in a range ,for eg: 2017-06-17,2017-06-18 and so on.

Comment: Include the traceback!

Comment: I Didn't get you.

Comment: Include the error text!

Comment: done , included in the question.

Comment: Do not `return`, instead `print date` in the function itself inside `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just looping over each date doing nothing and in the end, you're returning the last one.

```
# open a database connection
connection = MySQLdb.connect ()

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = connection.cursor ()

# execute the SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute ()

data = cursor.fetchall()
ddt =  sorted(set(data))

def dte():
    dates = [] #Here you need to store the dates in a list or something
    for row in ddt:
        dates.append(' '.join(map(str,row))) #Then append them to the list
    return(dates) #Finally return them EDITED

for i in dte(ddt):
    print(i)
```

> *One more thing, use `ddt` as an argument. Thus saving yourselves from scope problems.*

Like:

```
def dte(data):
          dates = [] #Here you need to store the dates in a list or something
          for row in data:
           dates.append(' '.join(map(str,row))) #Then append them to the list
          return(dates) #Finally return them

for i in dte(ddt):
     print(i)
```

Comment: thank you , is it possible to print them one below another without quotes?

Comment: Thank you,but then i can't print outside the for loop right?

Comment: No, you have to print within the `for's` code block only, as the variable `i` only exists within the `for's` scope.

Answer (score 0):

Do not `return`, instead `print date` in the function itself inside `for`.

```
# open a database connection 
connection = MySQLdb.connect () 

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method 
cursor = connection.cursor () 

# execute the SQL query using execute() method. 
cursor.execute () 

data = cursor.fetchall() 

ddt = sorted(set(data)) 

def dte(): 
    for row in ddt: 
        date = (' '.join(map(str,row))) 
        print(date)      
dte()
```